# Is it possible to continuously add in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, http, proxy

I'm using a node module to create http proxy servers (node-socks)like this:

```
const { http } = require('@sansamour/node-socks')




http.createServer({
    authorization: function(u,p){
        return u == 'KeemROH' && p == 'Test'
    },
    port: 5000
});

http.createServer({
    authorization: function(u,p){
        return u == 'KeemROH' && p == 'Test'
    },
    port: 5001
});

http.createServer({
    authorization: function(u,p){
        return u == 'KeemROH' && p == 'Test'
    },
    port: 5002
});

http.createServer({
    authorization: function(u,p){
        return u == 'KeemROH' && p == 'Test'
    },
    port: 5003
});

http.createServer({
    authorization: function(u,p){
        return u == 'KeemROH' && p == 'Test'
    },
    port: 5004
});
```

Would it maybe be possible to make a loop that would maybe run:

```
http.createServer({
    authorization: function(u,p){
        return u == 'KeemROH' && p == 'Test'
    },
    port: 5000 // add +1 each loop so 5000, 5001, 5002, 5003, 5004 ect.
});
```

And have it loop a set number of times?
So instead of rewriting it a number of times this can be the solution

Comment: `let port = 5000; http.createServer({..., port: port++});` ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey unfortunately this did not work

Comment: Sure, a loop should be trivially possible for the code you posted. Please show us your attempt.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "continuously". Your loop will need to stop at some point (5005 in your example). Also, why are you creating multiple proxy servers at all?

Comment: @Bergi In my situation this number may be configured to allow a set number of ports in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
const { http } = require('@sansamour/node-socks')

const numServers = 5;
const startingPort = 5000;

for (let i = 0; i < numServers; i++) {
    http.createServer({
        authorization: function(u,p){
            return u == 'KeemROH' && p == 'Test'
        },
        port: startingPort + i
    });
}
```